# Как правильно установить CI3 Fire starter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Всем привет!
Пытаюсь установить https://github.com/JasonBaier/ci3-fire-starter#installation. Все делаю по инструкции, но получаю 403 форбиден. Подозреваю, что дело в неверной настройки core.php.

Сейчас структура папок такая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл core.php

```html
// Site Details
$config['site_version']          = "1.0.0";     // this is CI3 Fire Starter version - set it to 1.0.0 for your new project
$config['root_folder']           = "htdocs";    // set to whatever your webroot is (htdocs, public_html, etc.) - MAKE SURE you physically rename the /htdocs folder if you change this value!
$config['public_theme']          = "default";   // folder containing your public theme
$config['admin_theme']           = "admin";     // folder containing your admin theme

// Pagination
$config['num_links']             = 8;
$config['full_tag_open']         = "<div class=\"pagination\">";
$config['full_tag_close']        = "</div>";

// Login Attempts
$config['login_max_time']        = 10;          // in seconds
$config['login_max_attempts']    = 3;

// Miscellaneous
$config['profiler']              = FALSE;
$config['error_delimeter_left']  = "";
$config['error_delimeter_right'] = "<br />";
```

Как быть и избавится от 403? 
Буду благодарен за любую помощь или направление

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в Web-сервере указали правильный путь к папке htdocs?
Уверен, что нет...

> Modify /application/config/core.php and set $config['root_folder'] to match your server's webroot (htdocs, public_html, etc.)